# How to add element from list to a dataframe as column preserving the order?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Imagine I have a list of three dataframes and a list with three names.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2],
                    'b':[2,3,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2],
                    'b':[2,2,1]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,2],
                    'b':[3,3,3]})
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
```

I would like to add a new column called 'DF_NAME' to each dataframe from the list with the items inside the other list 'names'. And this should be done in the order they appeared, so the result for each dataframe should be:

```
   a  b DF_NAME
0  0  2  df1
1  1  3  df1
2  2  1  df1

   a  b DF_NAME
0  1  2  df2
1  1  2  df2
2  2  1  df2

   a  b DF_NAME
0  0  3  df3
1  2  3  df3
2  2  3  df3
```

I'm trying to do a loop like this, but it just adds the last name of the list. Could you help me?

```
for data in df_list:
    for n in names:
        data['DF_NAME'] = n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `zip`:

```
for df, name in zip(df_list, names):
    df['DF_NAME'] = name
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much